# How to bypass ORA-01033 ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress for a regular user?

Tags: oracle

I have a Zabbix user that can't connect to the database in mount status, I need to bypass it. Is there any workarround? it must monitor if the instance is in mount status and trigger some alert, but it cannot connect when it is in mount status.

Answer (score 0):

Why trigger an alert only if the database is only in MOUNT stage?
Don't you want to trigger an alert when the database is shut down or is in NOMOUNT stage? Receiving such an error while attempting to connect as a regular user is an indicator good enough to trigger an alert.

If you insist on logging in to an instance in MOUNT stage, you need a user with at least one of the below  privileges:

```
SYSDBA
SYSOPER
SYSBACKUP
SYSDG
SYSKM
```

With `SYSDBA`, `SYSBACKUP` and `SYSDG`, the instance status can be queried from `V$INSTANCE`.